# Match array with array filed in ELASTICSEARCH

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-dsl

I have an index in ES where I stored my catalog. Documents are mix of string and array type (sample shown below):

```
{
  "_index" : "catalog",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "N1234",
  "_score" : 1.0,
  "_source" : {
    "product_id" : "1234",
    "name" : "Multifunctional Soapbox Hanging",
    "model" : "HS-11",
    "image" : "catalog/1.jpg",
    "size" : [
      "43",
      "44",
      "45"
    ],
    "color" : [
      "66",
      "67"
    ],
    "tag" : [
      "Soap Dish Rack Bathroom Essentials",
      "Plastic Bathroom Essentials",
      "Adhesive Bathroom Essentials",
      "Smart Accessories Bathroom Essentials",
      "Any Bathroom Essentials",
      "Brown Bathroom Essentials",
      "Bathroom Accessories Bathroom Essentials",
      "Bathroom Essentials"
    ],
    "language_id" : "1",
    "status" : "7",
    "date_added" : "2021-02-06 14:29:37"
  }
}
```

All documents are same structure. I want to query my index for similar products on basis of `Color` and `Tag` fields. Means, if I pass `color = 66` and `Tag = [ARRAY_OF_VALUES]`, it should return me most similar products sorted by score, which may contain same COLOR or maximum matching TAGS.

I tried `BOOL` query with `Should` or `Must` but no better results.

I have no idea how to query an array as both color and tags are arrays. Should I pass TAGS params as array or separate values and make individual `match` queries?

Query I tried (by @ESCoder):

```
"query": {
"bool": {
  "must": [
    {
      "terms": {
        "color": [
          "40" //code of blue color
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "should": [
    {
      "terms": {
        "tag": [
          "Casual Dresses",
          "Round Neck Dresses",
          "Short Sleeves Dresses",
          "Blue Dresses"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

}

Expected result:

All products containing same `color` and maximum similar `tag` , sorted by score

```
{
  "_index" : "catalog",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "N624121",
  "_score" : 39.43454,
  "_source" : {
    "color" : [
      "40"
    ],
    "size" : [
      "47",
      "48",
      "50",
      "51"
    ],
    "product_id" : "62412",
    "name" : "Girls Short Sleeve Fashion Short Dress - Blue",
    "model" : "LYQ001",
    "tag" : [
      "Casual Dresses",
      "Body Fitted Dresses",
      "Short Gown Dresses",
      "Slip Dress Dresses",
      "Blue Dresses"
    ]
  }
},
{
  "_index" : "catalog",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "N624151",
  "_score" : 39.046432,
  "_source" : {
    "color" : [
      "40"
    ],
    "size" : [
      "47",
      "48",
      "50",
      "51"
    ],
    "product_id" : "62415",
    "name" : "Girls Short Sleeve Fashion Short Dress - Sky Blue",
    "model" : "LYQ001",
    "tag" : [
      "Casual Dresses",
      "Body Fitted Dresses",
      "Short Sleeves Dresses",
      "Slip Dress Dresses",
      "Sky Blue Dresses"
    ]
  }
},
{
  "_index" : "catalog",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "N624111",
  "_score" : 38.569298,
  "_source" : {
    "color" : [
      "40"
    ],
    "size" : [
      "47",
      "48",
      "50",
      "51"
    ],
    "product_id" : "62411",
    "name" : "Girls Short Sleeve Fashion Short Dress - Navy blue",
    "model" : "LYQ001",
    "tag" : [
      "Casual Dresses",
      "Body Fitted Dresses",
      "Round Neck Dresses",
      "Slip Dress Dresses",
      "Black Dresses"
    ]
  }
},
{
  "_index" : "catalog",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "N624131",
  "_score" : 37.646904,
  "_source" : {
    "color" : [
      "40"
    ],
    "size" : [
      "47",
      "48",
      "50",
      "51"
    ],
    "product_id" : "62413",
    "name" : "Girls Short Sleeve Fashion Short Dress - light blue",
    "model" : "LYQ001",
    "tag" : [
      "Casual Dresses",
      "Body Fitted Dresses",
      "Short Gown Dresses",
      "Slip Dress Dresses",
      "light blue Dresses"
    ]
  }
},
{
  "_index" : "catalog",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "N624141",
  "_score" : 37.02933,
  "_source" : {
    "color" : [
      "233"
    ],
    "size" : [
      "47",
      "48",
      "50",
      "51"
    ],
    "product_id" : "62414",
    "name" : "Girls Short Sleeve Fashion Short Dress - Wine",
    "model" : "LYQ001",
    "tag" : [
      "Casual Dresses",
      "Body Fitted Dresses",
      "Round Neck Dresses",
      "Short Sleeves Dresses",
      "Wine Red Dresses"
    ]
  }
},
{
  "_index" : "catalog",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "N624161",
  "_score" : 36.39569,
  "_source" : {
    "color" : [
      "84"
    ],
    "size" : [
      "47",
      "48",
      "50",
      "51"
    ],
    "product_id" : "62416",
    "name" : "Girls Short Sleeve Fashion Short Dress - Rose",
    "model" : "LYQ001",
    "tag" : [
      "Casual Dresses",
      "Body Fitted Dresses",
      "Short Gown Dresses",
      "Slip Dress Dresses",
      "Blue Dresses"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please share your expected search result ?

Comment: @ESCoder Updated ... Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) to search for multiple values.

Terms query returns document having exact terms in the provided field (here `tag`).

**If you have not explicitly defined any mapping then you need to add .keyword to the `tag` field. This uses the keyword analyzer instead of the standard analyzer (notice the ".keyword" after `tag` field).**

Try out the below query

```
    {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "color": [
              "40" //code of blue color
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "tag.keyword": [
              "Casual Dresses",
              "Round Neck Dresses",
              "Short Sleeves Dresses",
              "Blue Dresses"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result will have all the documents with a score of 2.0**

---

But if you want to sort on the basis of score, then you need to use `bool/should` clause along with `term` query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "color": [
              "40" //code of blue color
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "tag.keyword": "Casual Dresses"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "tag.keyword": "Round Neck Dresses"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "tag.keyword": "Short Sleeves Dresses"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "tag.keyword": "Blue Dresses"
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Search Result will be

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67148091",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 2.640676,
        "_source": {
          "color": [
            "40"
          ],
          "size": [
            "47",
            "48",
            "50",
            "51"
          ],
          "product_id": "62412",
          "name": "Girls Short Sleeve Fashion Short Dress - Blue",
          "model": "LYQ001",
          "tag": [
            "Casual Dresses",
            "Body Fitted Dresses",
            "Short Gown Dresses",
            "Slip Dress Dresses",
            "Blue Dresses"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "67148091",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 2.640676,
        "_source": {
          "color": [
            "40"
          ],
          "size": [
            "47",
            "48",
            "50",
            "51"
          ],
          "product_id": "62415",
          "name": "Girls Short Sleeve Fashion Short Dress - Sky Blue",
          "model": "LYQ001",
          "tag": [
            "Casual Dresses",
            "Body Fitted Dresses",
            "Short Sleeves Dresses",
            "Slip Dress Dresses",
            "Sky Blue Dresses"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "67148091",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 2.640676,
        "_source": {
          "color": [
            "40"
          ],
          "size": [
            "47",
            "48",
            "50",
            "51"
          ],
          "product_id": "62411",
          "name": "Girls Short Sleeve Fashion Short Dress - Navy blue",
          "model": "LYQ001",
          "tag": [
            "Casual Dresses",
            "Body Fitted Dresses",
            "Round Neck Dresses",
            "Slip Dress Dresses",
            "Black Dresses"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "67148091",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 1.1101605,
        "_source": {
          "color": [
            "40"
          ],
          "size": [
            "47",
            "48",
            "50",
            "51"
          ],
          "product_id": "62413",
          "name": "Girls Short Sleeve Fashion Short Dress - light blue",
          "model": "LYQ001",
          "tag": [
            "Casual Dresses",
            "Body Fitted Dresses",
            "Short Gown Dresses",
            "Slip Dress Dresses",
            "light blue Dresses"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @Muhammad Hashir Anwaar please go through the answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: @Muhammad Hashir Anwaar there is no document in the expected search result having `"color"=66` ? What are the conditions on which you want the query ? Is this the condition `color = 66 and Tag = [ARRAY_OF_VALUES]` ?

Comment: Sir you answer make it a bit easier for me... I just changed the second `term` query in `should` array. Now it return new all products with same color whatever i pass, and match only few tags from given array.

Comment: @MuhammadHashirAnwaar glad this worked for you :-) So, have you got your expected search result ?

Comment: a bit sir. for last time, please take a look at QUERY I TIRED section and Result sections... i want to match `Tags` as well but for now i am only getting color matched.may be because of `SHOULD`

Comment: @MuhammadHashirAnwaar Sure, let me check

Comment: @MuhammadHashirAnwaar please go through the updated query in my answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: Still same result sir... I think should is ignoring tags also _score is always = 1.0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231275/discussion-between-escoder-and-muhammad-hashir-anwaar).